# Is there an algorithm for finding no. of k-weights hamiltonian paths in a 0-1 complete digraph

Tags: algorithm, graph, hamiltonian-path

I have a complete directed graph with n vertices. The edges are having 0-1 weights (i.e, they can have 0 or 1 as there weights). Also 1-weight edges are sparse i.e, there does not exist a hamiltonian path with more than n/2 weight. The problem is to find the no. of k-weight hamiltonian path for each k from 0 to n/2.